# What is a 'Linux Text Console', really?

Tags: command-line, hdmi, devices

What dev or resource in Linux actually constitutes being a 'console'?

I have a little, home, Linux box server that I usually SSH into.  I connected a TV to an HDMI output and wanted to 'startx' on it.  It complained that I was not a 'console' user.  (I did get X started by sudoing to root (/etc/X11/Xwrapper.conf contains: allowed_users=console) I connected a USB wireless keyboard and mouse and it worked)

**But**, programmatically what does it mean to be a '**linux text console**'?  Is it a /dev/tty, some /dev/hdmi? Being in /etc/groups 'console'?  Is it connecting to some Xserver TCP port?

I have 2 HDMI output ports and can have various real, wired, wireless or software 'keyboards' and 'mouse' HID devices.  How does Linux know or imagine what a 'console' is?

(After further research...) It seems different implementations/configurations can use different devices, some might use a serial port, some may use a screen (with hardware character display support (ie old glass teletype)) some may use a pixel oriented frame buffer.  How would I know what device to connect to to access my console?

Comment: I think it just means a ttyN user.

Comment: Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1   I would think this is a very basic matter, not dependent on distro version.

Comment: @Doug Smyhies It can't be related to a /dev/ttyX because there are lots of ttys and they have no specific relation to an HDMI / VGA device.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console

Comment: How many times do we get replies like oh it Pop OS or Zorin OS?

Comment: Why are you asking this? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @vidarlo I did 'startx' (from my SSH session)  it complained I was not a console user.  This got me to wonder what being a 'console' user was, It is not being in a 'console'  group in /etc/groups.  So I wanted to know what device I may need to send command to/from to be a console user.  (I later found that being 'su' worked, but want to know what they meant by 'console' user.

Comment: @Ribo I would suggest [edit]ing your question to match the comment :)

Comment: @vidarlo. I don't see how the question doesn't match the comment   The HDMI stuff is what lead to the question of what it means to be a linux text console